# Modify class property inside another class in a static method without static reference

Tags: c#, class, inner-classes

I have a `Time` class containing custom `+` logic, where an exception is thrown is the `Hours` become higher than 23. I also have a `Workshift` class which has a `Day` property and where I'd like to use `Time` as properties, but with a minor difference in addition logic: when the hours go over 23, change the day, thus I've created a `WorkingTime` class which inherits from `Time`, but changes the operator's behavior. At first I thought I could pass a `Workshift` reference into the `WorkingTime` class and just control it from there, but, aside from this (most likely) being a catastrophic design... My problem is: I don't know how to change the day, because overloading operator requires a static `Workshift` reference, and the it cannot be static for this to work as intended. How do I make that happen?
Here's the code I've come up with so far:

```
public class Time
{
    public ushort Hours { get; private set; }
    public ushort Minutes { get; private set; }

    public Time(ushort hours, ushort minutes)
    {
        if (hours > 23 || minutes > 59)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid time specified");
        }
        Hours = hours;
        Minutes = minutes;
    }

    public static Time operator +(Time a, Time b)
    {
        var hoursResult = a.Hours + b.Hours;
        var minutesResult = a.Minutes + b.Minutes;
        if (minutesResult > 59)
        {
            hoursResult += 1;
            minutesResult = minutesResult - 60;
        }
        if (hoursResult > 23)
            throw new Exception("Too many hours!");

        ushort hours = (ushort)hoursResult;
        ushort minutes = (ushort)minutesResult;
        return new Time(hours, minutes);
    }
}

public class Workshift
{
    public Day Day { get; set; }
    public WorkingTime StartHour { get; set; }
    public WorkingTime EndHour { get; set; }

    private class WorkingTime : Time
    {
        private Workshift _workshiftReference;
        public WorkingTime(ushort hours, ushort minutes, Workshift workshift) : base(hours, minutes)
        {
            _workshiftReference = workshift;
        }

        public static WorkingTime operator +(WorkingTime a, WorkingTime b)
        {
            var hoursResult = a.Hours + b.Hours;
            var minutesResult = a.Minutes + b.Minutes;
            if (minutesResult > 59)
            {
                hoursResult += 1;
                minutesResult = minutesResult - 60;
            }
            if (hoursResult > 23)
                _workshiftReference.Day++; //how do I achieve this?

            ushort hours = (ushort)hoursResult;
            ushort minutes = (ushort)minutesResult;
            return new WorkingTime(hours, minutes, _workshiftReference);
        }
    }
}
```

The high-level goal is to, for example, set day from Friday to Saturday when someone tries to add 3 hours to a `Time` which has 22 `Hours` and 30 `Minutes`. So {Friday, 22, 30} becomes {Saturday, 1, 30}.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that operator overloading requires a static class? The operator overload method needs to be static, but the class that contains it does not. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/how-to-use-operator-overloading-to-create-a-complex-number-class

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but I have a strong feeling like you are re-inventing the wheel here.  Can you try to describe at a high level what this code is supposed to do or what your ultimate intention for it is?

Comment: This is a mess, nested classes don't have any kind of link to the instance that owns them. We also have no idea what `Day` is, so we can't tell you how to "increment" it.

Comment: @CraigW. my bad, I meant it requires a static reference (at line `_workshiftReference.Day++;`), editing right now

Comment: @maccettura added high level goal
@RonBeyer yes, as I already said, I'm aware this is not the perfect code, I'd say that's one of the main reasons why I'm asking for help. `Day` can be anything really, youo can assume it's an enum if it helps you.

Comment: @Amai have you ever used `System.DateTime`?

Comment: @maccettura I have and I'm pretty sure I don't want to use it here, since it contains a lot of other unnecessary info I'd have to handle and initialize and care about while I'm only interested in less than a quarter than what it offers.

Comment: @Amai If you have a big hammer that will do the job easily, its not always the best choice to spend time making a slightly smaller hammer

Comment: @maccettura I prefer not to start up a tank and grab 3 molotov cocktails just to kill a single spider. I'd say just a hand or a flipper is enough.

Comment: Too each their own, but I like staying efficient and not wasting time solving problems that were solved and built long before me (and by people fair smarter than me).  Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Because the overloaded WorkingTime operator is static, when it is called it won't know what `_workshiftReference` is as it is tied to a member of an non static object.

You could make working time static and give the day field get/set functions. Or you could not overload the `+ operator` and make a function with three parameters that takes (Time A, Time B, Workshift work).

It looks like you are adding all these nested classes just to make the overloaded `+ operator` work, so I would maybe re-look into how your implementing what you are trying to do. Maybe just regular functions would work better.

Comment: Making a property static makes it so it is shared among every instance of that class, that is definiteljy not something I'd like to achieve with any of these classes. As for the going for methods approach: I'm trying to make the underlying implementation as seamless as possible so that someone using it won't have to know the underlying details and can just use that class without wondering 'Why do I have to pass such an object? It makes no sense' when simply trying to add 15 hours to 10 hours.